# Laravel 8: How to check if table empty or not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop my project, and in this project, I have a Controller named `HomeController` that his this method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $questions = Question::latest()->limit(5)->get();
        return view('home', compact('questions'));
    }
```

And then I get results like this on blade:

```
@php
    if ($questions)
    {
@endphp
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive BKoodakBold">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
        <th scope="col" class="forum-col" style="text-align:right;">Question</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">Answer</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">Rate</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align:right;">Views</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach($questions as $question)
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:right;">
            <h3 class="h5 mb-0"><a href="#0" class="text-uppercase">{{ $question->title }}</a></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@php
    }
@endphp
```

As you can see I set `if ($questions)` to check if this variable is not empty, do the for each loop next. And if it is empty, it should not show the table `thead`  tags.

But now the problem is it does not work out... I mean even if I have no data at the DB, it still shows table `thead`  completely.

So what is wrong with this code? How can I properly check if the table is empty or not?

I really appreciate it if you share your idea about this... Thanks.

Comment: you have a Collection which is an object which is always truthy `true` in PHP

Comment: @lagbox So what do I have to do now instead ?

Comment: @if (isset($questions) && !empty($questions) && count($questions) > 0)@endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check additional condition as

```
&& count($questions) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're returning collection, it's always true `compact('questions')`

Use

```
if (!$questions->isEmpty())  # Laravel(in-built) way
```

---

```
if (!$questions->isEmpty())
  // show data
else
  echo "No record found.";
```

Comment: you can't use `empty` for this

Comment: @lagbox Thank and `isEmpty` will work with collections.

Comment: @lagbox okay. Noted

Answer (score 1):

check with this condition

```
    @if (isset($questions) && count($questions) > 0)

       Inside Code

    @endif
```

Comment: you can't use `empty` for this

Comment: @lagbox Okay got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve an elocuent collection always, even if no data received. But collection is countable, so you can check it by

```
if(count($collection))
```

if count return zero then the sentence is assume like false